# error: name Twitter not defined on using import twitter

Tags: python, twitter

I used `import twitter` and then tried authenticating using the following command - `Twitter(auth=OAuth(access_token, access_token_secret, consumer_key, secret_key))`

On running the program I get the error: name Twitter not defined. When I use `from twitter import *`, it works. Why is it so?

I am asking this because if i use tweepy instead, a simple `import tweepy`works. Also, doesn't `import twitter` work the same as `from twitter import *`?

Comment: Importing a module does not make all the components _inside_ the module directly visible; you have to prepend the module name as in `twitter.Twitter(...)`.  As you noted, using `from module import *` does make the items _inside_ the module directly visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `twitter.Twitter (auth=OAuth(access_token, access_token_secret, consumer_key, secret_key))`